# Corrupted exports after ggplot2 object with grid.draw output

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a ggplot2 plot style. The `theme_custom()` function handles the adjusted themes. The difficult part is the part that overwrites the margins of the `title`, `subtitle` and the `caption`. My goal with the `finalise_plot()` function is to align the text tot the utmost left side of the plot.

The plot looks almost like I want to have it only now I stumble upon export issues. When I try to save the image (through the plot Device) as a pdf it removes all the text. When I export it in svg it gets corrupted.

Is there a way to export the exact output in svg as in the example below?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

theme_custom <- function(){
  theme_minimal() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",
                                    family = "Arial",
                                    size = 24),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "bold",
                                       family = "Arial",
                                       size = 20),
          plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0,
                                      color = "#6c737b",
                                      size = 18,
                                      family = "Arial"),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 18,
                                   color = "#1d2939",
                                   family = "Arial"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(color = "#6b38e8",
                                      family = "Arial",
                                      size = 18,
                                      hjust = 0),
          axis.text.y = element_text(color = "#6b38e8"),
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#f2f2f2",
                                         color = 0),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.grid = element_line(color = "#d8cedb",
                                    size = 0.75),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          plot.margin = unit(c(10,0,0,0),"pt"))
}

finalise_plot <- function() {

  table_grob <- ggplotGrob(p)

  table_grob$layout$l[table_grob$layout$name %in% c("title", "subtitle", "caption")] <- 1

  grid::grid.draw(table_grob)

}

p <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width,
             color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_custom() +
  labs(title = "Main title",
       subtitle = "Subtitle",
       caption = "UCI Machine Learning Repository",
       x = NULL)

finalise_plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

**pdf export:**
[image]

**svg export:**

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. I was able to export the output from `finalise_plot` into a SVG file just fine. Can you elaborate on your export process?

Comment: I just used the plots export option `Save as image` in the RStudio IDE...

Comment: Same here. Worked fine.

Comment: What's the best way to export without using the IDE shortcuts?

Comment: Don't know about best, but I usually default to `ggsave`.